# How can I test  an app in Unity without installing Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, drivers, 11.04, live-cd

I want to test my Ubuntu app on Unity.

I tried installing 11.04 on a VMWare virtual machine. I get a dialog saying I don't have 3d support so I can't turn on Unity. I learn that 3d drivers are not available for Ubuntu on VMWare.

So I figure, I'll just use the live CD on my computer itself. (i.e., no VM.) I load the live CD, install the NVidia drivers, but then it asks me to restart in order to use the driver. But if I restart, everything is lost because it's a live CD! I don't want to install Ubuntu on my computer, I just want to try out my app on it.

What can I do?

Comment: As long as it cannot be run on a virtual machine it will be hard to get developers to adapt their apps for Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running Unity in a VM is a current limitation. Installing it to a USB stick should work better for you:

[How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

Answer (score 0):

You can test the nvidia drivers from a LiveCD but it's not for the weak-hearted.

1. Boot up to the LiveCD
2. Install the drivers through jocky (the GUI installer)
3. Control+Alt+F1. This should take you to a black login screen.
4. Enter `ubuntu` as the username, no password
5. `sudo restart gdm`

This should dump you back in gnome with nvidia drivers installed. If that doesn't work, you might need to do a `sudo modprobe nvidia` before you restart `gdm`.